# Can I do it with histogram (frequency distribution)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have extracted the frames from video and converted into the optical flow looks like this;

[image]

You can clearly see that there are some frames that are giving information of an moving object (frame000037, frame000039, so on) and some are static (frame000038, frame000040, frame000042, so on).

I have read both frames static one and moving one to see the differences using OpenCV, Can anyone tell me who can I filter out those all frames that contains the motion information?

I have taken mean, standard deviation, normalization, but they didn't worked for me as the pixels value can be greater for the static than movable and in some from it can be less than the movable therefore it didn't work for every case.

Comment: Seems that empty frames  appears every two frames. There is no information every two frames .  So, first ,  you can consider to process only not empty frames.  May be the problem is not opencv  but your frame rate.

Comment: what exactly is the issue with calculating suitable statistics on the optical flow? should be trivial to come up with *two thresholds*, one to label each pixel as moving/static, and another that says how many pixels in total are moving/not moving. -- yes, a simple histogram gives more information but you don't need more.

Comment: I can't believe that the standard deviation does not work. And as pointed by Mario, every other frame is quiet, and this is abnormal.

Comment: Every second frame is static because it is not moving right after the movable frame. this is not in the case for all frames, there are frame that are consecutively in motion. Anything would you suggest me to get difference between the two frame and then can able to select those frame that are movable.

Comment: static frames are probably from someone converting the video badly, or not knowing about frame rates when editing the raw footage. -- you ought to plot the **magnitude** of the motion vectors instead of whatever you do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `np.sum` white pixels of each frame and use results as weight. Your empty frame result will be constant , equal to the area of the frame. So you can check if the frame is empty or not .

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1=cv2.imread("/tmp/frame0.bmp",0)
img2=cv2.imread("/tmp/frame1.bmp",0)

th = 150

ret, m1 = cv2.threshold(img1,th,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
ret, m2 = cv2.threshold(img2,th,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

n_pix1 = np.sum(m1 == 255)
n_pix2 = np.sum(m2 == 255)

print(n_pix1,n_pix2)


cv2.imshow("1",m1)
cv2.imshow("2",m2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]